# Insert object (as a folder) in Google Cloud Storage using JSON API with Java

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

I already know that there is no folders inside a Google Cloud Storage (they are treated as objects), so please have a look of my question and you can understand what i mean. Thanks :-)

This is my method to upload an object, and in my specific case, i would like to upload a "folder", so a file that end with a '/' (for example: 'newfolder/'), but i receive a GoogleJson error in the execute() at the end of my code.

[Error]:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 OK
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  }, {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  }, {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Required"
}
```

[my code inside the method]:

```
StorageObject objectMetadata = null;

        //default bucket
        String bucketRootName = “defaultbucketname”;

        //First Folder
        String folderAppName = “myfolder”;

        //folder that i want to create (upload)
        folderName+="/";
        String folderPath = folderAppName + "/" + folderName;

        if (useCustomMetadata) {

            List<ObjectAccessControl> acl = Lists.newArrayList();
            acl.add( new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allAuthenticatedUsers").setRole("OWNER"));

            objectMetadata = new StorageObject()

            .setName(folderPath)
            .setAcl(acl)
            .setContentDisposition("attachment");
        }

        Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storage.objects().insert(bucketRootName, objectMetadata);

        StorageObject metadata = insertObject.execute();
        return metadata;
```

In order to have a bucket with a path like this:
defaultbucketname/myfolder/folderName/

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you so much

Comment: don't you just upload the new file with a path of "inside the folder". I don't think you can upload an empty "folder" as such, it's just all virtual paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploaded objects **must** have a Content-Type, even if they're zero bytes large.

Also, I'm pretty sure that you must upload an actual file, even if it is zero bytes in size.

Comment: Which Content-Type do you suggest?

Comment: The Google Developers Console browser uses "text/plain" when inserting folder objects.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can create a folder that way. But you can create it while uploading the file by setting the name.

e.g. if you want create a file under foldA/foldB/test.txt, you can do it following way.

```
    InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path); //path if java.nio.file.Path
    String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(path);
    InputStreamContent isContent = new InputStreamContent(mimeType, is);
    StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject();

    Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storage.objects().insert(bucketRootName, objectMetadata,isContent);

    insertObject.setName("foldA/foldB/"+path.getFileName().toString()); // path.getFileName().toString() will give u test.txt
    insertObject.execute();
```